# Scanning for iBeacons on OSX

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, osx-yosemite, ibeacon

Is there a good way to scan for iBeacons (Estimote in my case) on OSX? I've tried BeaconScanner and ibeacon app but they are flunky at best. The log for ibeacon without any movement of the computer nor the beacons looks like this: https://gist.github.com/michalsapka/0dcfd7b954632bdf28b6

Answer (score 2):

Your experience on OSX matches mine.  You can use it as a tool to look for beacons, but won't pick up packets very reliably, and is certainly not an ideal tool for production use.